# List appending appends more values than expected

Tags: python

I tried to do a function that takes a list of messages and a list of authors, and puts every message in it's corresponding author's message list.

```py
class Author:
    name = ""
    msgs = []
    files = []

class Message:
    line = ""
    time = datetime
    author = ""
```

Function mentioned

```py
for au in authorList:
    a = 0
    for msg in msgList:
        if au.name == msg.author:
            a += 1
            au.msgs.append(msg)
    print(a)

for au in authorList:
    print(len(au.msgs))
```

And the output of the program

```
a=396
a=349
745
745
```

The function takes au.name and msg.author and compares them, if they are equal, the msg is stored in au.msgs list.

The variable a is incremented everytime a message is added to the user, and as it can be seen, for the first user `a = 396` and for the second user `a = 349` which sum 745, which is the size of the msgList.

The problem is that each author.msgList ends holding the total number of messages.

I have to mention that I am low skilled in python, so it might be a simple noob problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `msgs` and `files` are class variables, not instance variables, so they are shared by all instances of `Author`.

You can define them as instance variables as follows:

```
class Author:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ''
    self.msgs = []
    self.files = []
```

As suggested by TheGamer007, consider having a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-34-class-or-static-variables-in-python/

Comment: You can check this out for a longer explanation - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-34-class-or-static-variables-in-python/